# Having problems with fade in

Tags: video, blender

I have a video with an overlay that i need to fade in. When i add a crossfade it starts fully opaque and then fades out. The exact opposite of what i want to achieve. How do i reverse the crossfade effect without also reversing the video?

Answer (score 2):

If the overlay has transparency, you could use an Add strip instead. Then keyframe the Multiply setting for it going from 0.0 (invisible) to 1.0 (fully visible).